# Makefile issue: No rule to make target as a dependency, but can make the target directly from command line?

Tags: linux, makefile

My makefile currently looks like

```
PROPS_FILE      =   ${PWD}/AnglesViews_vs2015.vcxproj
include             $(or ${RULES}, $$RULES)

TRANSVIEW_DIR = ${SIMBASHARED_DIR}/Transview/Trunk
TRANSVIEW_LIB = ${TRANSVIEW_DIR}/${CONFIG}/lib/transview.a

all : AnglesViews.${SO}
AnglesViews.${SO} : AnglesViews.o ${TRANSVIEW_LIB}
#AnglesViews.o : ${TRANSVIEW_DIR}/source/transview.h

DESTDIR.bin     =   ${SIMBAENGINE_DIR}/Bin/${CONFIG}

##- - - - - - - |- - - - - - - -|- - - - - - - -|- - - - - - - -|- - - - - - - -|
CPPFLAGS        +=  ${CURL_FLAGS}  ${CORESDK_FLAGS} -I${TRANSVIEW_DIR}/source
LDLIBS          +=  ${CURL_LIBS}  ${OPENSSL_LIBS}  ${ZLIB_LIBS}  ${ODBCSDK_LIBS} ${TRANSVIEW_LIB}

##--------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
# BOILERPLATE
CPPFLAGS        +=  ${IncDirs:%=-I%}  ${PROPS_FLAGS}  ${TOOLS_FLAGS}
LDLIBS          +=  ${LibDirs:%=-L%}  ${PROPS_LIBS}  $(filter-out -lwin%, ${LibNames:%=-l%})
vpath %.cpp     $.  ${SrcDirs}
```

It depends on a lot of machinery from the included ${RULES} file, which I don't want to share right now.

In the same directory as the makefile, there's a file AnglesViews.cpp, and I'm relying on an implicit rule to allow AnglesViews.o to be made from that.

If I try to build the target 'all' or 'AnglesViews.so' (which is what AnglesViews.${SO} resolves to on linux, where I'm doing this), I get an error that there is no target to build 'AnglesViews.o'. But if I try to build the target 'AnglesViews.o' directly, it does it!

So why is make lying to me?

Another strange thing I noticed was that if I uncommented the line '#AnglesViews.o : ${TRANSVIEW_DIR}/source/transview.h', then make would go and try to build the final binary without even complaining about the missing object file.

edit: The implicit rule I'm relying on is the following (from make -p)

```
%.cpp:

%.o: %.cpp
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Platform & version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux sen-centos7-01 3.10.0-1062.18.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 17 23:49:17 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gmake --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I ran 'make -d' on 'all' & 'AnglesViews.o' & removed the common prefix:
all:

```
Considering target file `all'.
 File `all' does not exist.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `AnglesViews.so'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.a'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.o'.
  Found an implicit rule for `AnglesViews.so'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Transview/Trunk/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/lib/transview.a'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `transview'.
   Found an implicit rule for `/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Transview/Trunk/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/lib/transview.a'.
 Considering target file `AnglesViews.so'.
  File `AnglesViews.so' does not exist.
  Considering target file `AnglesViews.o'.
   File `AnglesViews.o' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `AnglesViews.o'.
  Must remake target `AnglesViews.o'.
```

`AnglesViews.o':

```
Considering target file `AnglesViews.o'.
 File `AnglesViews.o' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `AnglesViews.o'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.c'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.cc'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.C'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.cpp'.
 Found an implicit rule for `AnglesViews.o'.
  Considering target file `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.l'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.cpp,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/AnglesViews.cpp,v'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `s.AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.l'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `AnglesViews.l'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `AnglesViews.l,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/AnglesViews.l,v'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/AnglesViews.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `s.AnglesViews.l'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `AnglesViews.l'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.AnglesViews.l'.
   No implicit rule found for `AnglesViews.cpp'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `AnglesViews.cpp'.
  No need to remake target `AnglesViews.cpp'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `AnglesViews.o'.
Must remake target `AnglesViews.o'.
Invoking builtin recipe to update target `AnglesViews.o'.
g++55 -DxCXX -DxC -g -m64 -lpthread -O3 -DxCgxx -fPIC -pthread -MMD -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector --param ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wall -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-security -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wunused -Wwrite-strings -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-switch -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-error -UxCgxx -UxC -DxCgxx -fPIC -pthread -MMD -fdiagnostics-show-option -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector --param ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wall -Wextra -Wformat=2 -Wformat-security -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wunused -Wwrite-strings -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-cast-qual -Wno-format-nonliteral -Wno-switch -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-error -UxCgxx -Wno-overflow -Wno-reorder -Wno-int-in-bool-context -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-variable -UxCXX  -DxCPP -DHAVE_LONG_LONG -D_REENTRANT -DSIMBA -DSQL_WCHART_CONVERT -D_THREAD_SAFE -DSIZEOF_LONG_INT=8 -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -UxCPP -I/home/mattheww/perforce/ThirdParty/libcURL/7.74.0_ssl1.1.1_zlib1.2.11_threaded_resolver/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/include  -DxCORESDK -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/. -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/DSI -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/DSI/Client -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support/Exceptions -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support/Queues -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support/Threading -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support/TypedDataWrapper -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/ThirdParty/odbcheaders -UxCORESDK -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Transview/Trunk/source -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/SENPlugin -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support/Exceptions -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaEngine/Maintenance/10.1/Product/Include/Support/TypedDataWrapper -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Tools/Maintenance/1.0/source -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Transview/Trunk/source -I/home/mattheww/perforce/ThirdParty/rapidjson/20160518/include  -DxPROPS       -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Step/Maintenance/1.1/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/Include -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Tools/Maintenance/1.0/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/Include -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/PackageRenamer/Maintenance/1.0/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/Include -I/home/mattheww/perforce/ThirdParty/icu/58.3.x/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/include -I/home/mattheww/perforce/ThirdParty/openssl/1.1.1/centos7/gcc5_5/release64/include -UxPROPS  -I/home/mattheww/perforce/SimbaShared/Tools/Maintenance/1.0/source     -c -o AnglesViews.o AnglesViews.cpp
Putting child 0x9ed3d0 (AnglesViews.o) PID 31879 on the chain.
Live child 0x9ed3d0 (AnglesViews.o) PID 31879 
Reaping winning child 0x9ed3d0 PID 31879 
Removing child 0x9ed3d0 PID 31879 from chain.
Successfully remade target file `AnglesViews.o'.
```

edit: After doing some refactoring & splitting the 'god-file' into smaller ones, I'm getting the same error, still on AnglesViews.o, and it's still fixed by explicitly building AnglesViews.o, so there's something special about that file (as it's not happening for the other source/object files)

The only changed line is

```
AnglesViews.${SO} : AnglesViews.o ConnectionSettings.o FilteredRowset.o MergedSortedRowsets.o Plugin.o PluginContext.o RowComparator.o RowStoreRowSet.o SchemaIterator.o SortedRowset.o ViewIterator.o ${TRANSVIEW_LIB}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've shown us there's no reason for that, so the reason must be due to something you haven't shown us.  For example, your implicit rule may have extra prerequisites that can't be resolved.  To debug this, you should run `make -p` and see what the catalog of rules is.  Then also run `make -d` for both types of build and see what the difference is WRT `AnglesViews.o` (it will be a lot of output).

Alternatively, try to reduce your problem to a small example that you can share here so we can see the entire thing.

Also when asking for help with make, please be sure to mention which type of make you're using (GNU make here, presumably), the version you're using, and the platform you're using (and if it's Windows, whether GNU make was built with cygwin, MinGW32, Visual Studo, etc.)